# $(0,1)$ homeomorphic to $(0,1)$

Tags: general-topology

> Show that $(0,1)$ with the subspace topology on the real line $\mathbb R$ homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ with the metric topology.

*I did:*

Two topological spaces $X,Y$ are homeomorphic if there exists two continues  functions $f:X\to Y\\g:Y\to X$ such that $g\circ f=id_X$ and $f\circ g=id_Y$

than I thought to define the function $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x$ therefore $f\circ g=g\circ f=x$.

what do you think?

Comment: Hu? The metric on $(0,1)$ is the restriction of the metric of $\Bbb R$ after all ...

Comment: subspace topology: If X is a topological space, and $A\subseteq X$ is a subset, you can think of it as a topological space (or subspace of X) having its own topology. The subspace topology $(A,\tau_A)$ is such that $U\subseteq A$ is an open set if and only if $U=V\cap A$ for a $U$ open in X.

Comment: Identity map between two topological spaces (same set with different topologies) is not necessarily continuous. You would have to prove $f(x)=x$ is indeed a continuous map, i.e for any $U\in\tau_Y$, $f^{-1}(U)\in\tau_X$

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: The usual topology on $\mathbb R$ can be defined either as the metric topology or the order topology and it's the same topology either way.

Comment: Am I the only one who's up-voted the question so far?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:((0,1),\mathcal{T}_{s})\to((0,1),\mathcal{T}_{m})$ with $f(x)=x$, where $\mathcal{T}_{s}$ is the subspace topology and $\mathcal{T}_m$ is the metric topology.

When we say "subspace topology", we mean the topology "inherited" to $(0,1)$ from $\mathbb{R}$ by intersections of all open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ with $(0,1)$. On the other hand, the metric topology of $(0,1)$ is the topology induced from the metric defined on $(0,1)$. In our case, this metric is a restriction of the usual metric of $\mathbb{R}$, so it is easy to prove that $\mathcal{T}_s=\mathcal{T}_m$.

For this purpose, let $A\in\mathcal{T}_s$. Then, there exist a $G\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, open, such that:
$$A=G\cap(0,1)$$
Since $(0,1)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ - crucial point - it is evident that $A$ is also an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, as well. So $$A=\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$$
where $B_i=B(x_i,r_i)$ are open balls with $\mathbb{R}$'s usual metric topology. Since
$$B_i\subset A\subset(0,1)$$
for every $i\in I$, we have that $B_i\subseteq(0,1)$ and, hence they are also open in $\mathcal{T}_m$, so $A\in\mathcal{T}_m$, which means that $\mathcal{T}_s\subseteq\mathcal{T}_m$.

Let now $A\in\mathcal{T}_m$. Then $$A=\bigcup_{j\in J}B_j$$
where $B_j=B(x_j,r_j)$ are balls with the metric topology of $(0,1)$. But, in that case, since $(0,1)$'s metric is a restriction of $\mathbb{R}$'s metric, we have that $B_j$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}$'s usual topology for every $j\in J$. So $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Now it is evident, since
$$A=A\cap(0,1)$$
that $A\in\mathcal{T}_s$. So $\mathcal{T}_m\subseteq\mathcal{T}_s$.

Finally $\mathcal{T}_s=\mathcal{T}_m$.

Now, it is trivial to show that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I did not vote down this question. However, it is in general suggested that a little search has been done before asking - I'm reffering to the fact that you could have first searched for the term "subspace" topology. But, every-one has the right to make mistakes and that's OK from my viewpoint! :)